# Regex search pattern in very large file

Tags: java, regex

I'd like to search pattern in very large file (f.e above 1 GB) that consists of single line. 
It is not possible to load it into memory. Currently, I use `BufferedReader`to read into buffers (1024 chars).
The main steps:

1. Read data into two buffers
2. Search pattern in that buffers
3. Increment variable if pattern was found
4. Copy second buffer into first
5. Load data into second buffers
6. Search pattern in both buffers.
7. Increment variable if pattern was found
8. Repeat above steps (start from 4) until EOF

That algorithm (two buffers) lets me to avoid situation, where searched piece of text is split by chunks. It works like a chram unless pattern result is smaller that two buffers length. For example I can't manage with case, when result is longer - let's say long as 3 buffers (but I've only data in two buffers, so match will fail!). What's more, I can realize such a case:

1. Prepare 1 GB single line file, that consits of "baaaaaaa(....)aaaaab"
2. Search for pattern `ba*b`.
3. The whole file match pattern!
4. **I don't have to print the result, I've only to be able to say: "Yea, I was able to find pattern" or "No, I wasn't able to find that".**

It's possible with java? I mean:

1. Ability to determine, whether a pattern is present in file (without loading whole line into memory, see case above
2. Find the way handle the case, when  match result is longer than chunk.

I hope my explanation is pretty clear.

Comment: Are you familiar with Java's [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class?  It looks like a perfect fit to me.  It does its own buffering, and correctly handles the run-on matches you're talking about.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think the solution for you would be to implement [`CharSequence`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) as a wrapper over very large text files.

Why? Because building a `Matcher` from a `Pattern` takes a `CharSequence` as an argument.

Of course, easier said than done... But then you only have three methods to implement, so that shouldn't be too hard...

---

**EDIT** I took the plunge and I [ate my own dog's food](https://github.com/fge/largetext). The "worst part" is that it actually works!

Comment: Hm... If Matcher does not cache chars, but only iterates through array.. it could solution.

Comment: Well, maybe it does, haven't looked at the implementation ;)

Comment: Note: also have a look at the `CharsetDecoder` class, it will be of immense help

Comment: Interesting idea. One issue would be that `Matcher` bounces around the string-being-searched (with backtracking and such) when attempting to find the match, which implies that multiple buffers  may *have* to be entirely in memory.

Comment: @aliteralmind yes, that is true; however, the `CharsetDecoder` can help here. This and `FileChannel.map()`.

Comment: The other problem is random access to char (via charAt). If it's is going about the buffered reader, I'd have to reset the whole BufferedReader in order to "back to desired char" - like @aliteralminf wrote (I've just noticed :))

Comment: pwas: "The other problem is random access to char (via charAt)." I think that's a different way of saying the same thing: It needs to backtrack at any time. @fge: Not familiar with those classes. I'll take a look.

Comment: @pwas yes, this is not going to be easy... Meh, might be a good project to have a go at. I'll need to experiment with `CharsetDecoder`: it doesn't say whether the input `ByteBuffer` is changed at the issue of the decoding operation. If it is, that'll be much easier.

Comment: @pwas good news: a decoder _does_ modify the position of the input `ByteBuffer`. So the job is easier...

Comment: Thanks for you time and POC! I'll try to implement it today (after workhours).

Comment: @pwas ate my own dogfood: https://github.com/fge/largetext -- might be of interest to someone else after all ;)

Comment: Hmm, I've done implementing charAt :) Tommorrow I'll perform some performance tests with very large files and behaviour with Regex.

Comment: @pwas uh, for _all_ encodings? Does a text file with "Mémé" in it in UTF-8 will return 'm' if you .charAt(2)? :)

Comment: Yeep, it returns 'm'. Currently, it's ugly implemented, I need to do some refactor and implement subString. I've tested Matcher and it is not using subString, but I cannot left it not implemented. I'll also try to figure out encoding detecting. Your samples on github was very useful :).

Comment: Sure: http://pastebin.com/9x13Xmji It's based mostly on your code, contrib wil be added. I'll host whole project when it's done (in one-two weeks).

Comment: @pwas see the link above again; I have fully implemented it with caching etc

Comment: This, and grappa, they have eradicated made my ANSYS-mechanical report parsing blues. Thanks for such a cool library!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you may need to break that search-pattern down into pieces, since, given your restrictions, searching for it in its entirety is failing.

Can you determine that a buffer contains the *beginning* of a match? If so, save that state and then search the next portion for the next part of the match. Continue until the entire search-term is found.

Comment: yeah, I was about to write this answer myself. If you have only need to know that it exists, try to find start. Load in data to the buffer, Once you have that search for the start, once you have stat begin searching for the End pattern, load new data into buffer as needed. If you find the end pattern before EOF, then your pattern exists in the file.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm able to determine wheter buffer contains the beginnging of a match only, when it is possible with Regex. I do not know if it possible with java.

Comment: Sounds good. So I need to find find a way, to match pattern partially (f.e. only beginning with the regex and java).

Comment: If your search string is as easy as "ba*b" it shouldn't be too difficult. It'll just be a bit mind-twisting to keep the state straight as you iterate through the buffers, deleting all state when the next portion doesn't correctly continue the match. It's an interesting problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, search string is not so simple.. My algorithm should handle with any valid regex pattern.

Comment: Well, it's the same concept. It'll just be a bit more mind twisting perhaps. Create some testing code, with expected responses and state (what it should be when two buffers start a match, but then the next one doesn't continue it properly, for example) before you even start coding this. Good luck.

Comment: so, you're basically creating a method that can match regexes in REALLY large files?

Comment: Well.. yes. But like I've said - I don't want to to print result. I just want to search for pattern occurence. @aliteralmind - thanks, I'll try your concept! Like I've also said, it sounds very promissing.