# Java: regex replacement in large files

Tags: java, regex

Java `java.util.regex.Matcher` [`replaceFirst(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceFirst-java.lang.String-)/[`replaceAll(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-) API returns strings, which (if using the default heap size) may well cause an OOME for inputs as large as 20-50M characters. These 2 methods can be easily rewritten to [write](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write-char:A-) to `Writer`s rather than construct stings, effectively eliminating one point of failure.

The `Matcher`'s [factory method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matcher-java.lang.CharSequence-), however, only accepts `CharSequence`s, which is also likely to throw an OOME if I use `String`s/`StringBuffer`s/`StringBuilder`s.

How do I wrap a `java.io.Reader` to implement a `CharSequence` interface (given the fact that my regexps may contain *backreferences*)?
Is there any other solution which can replace regexps in files and is not OOME-prone on large inputs?

In other words, how do I implement a functionality similar to that of GNU `sed` in Java (as `sed` is known to tackle files as large as a couple terabytes, while featuring the same support for extended regular expressions)?

Comment: Do you only need to replace a single line at a time, or support "whole file in one go" replacements?

Comment: `Pattern.matcher()` doesn't create new String. The `Matcher` object created just hold a reference to the CharSequence passed in.

Comment: `sed` handles files on a line-by-line basis, which is the reason it doesn't require a lot of memory for large files (unless the file has *very* long lines or the code instructs it to remember a lot of stuff). If you do the same in Java (i.e., read a line, work on it, print it, read the next line, rinse, repeat), you'll require similar amounts of memory. By the way, you may be interested in [Unix4j](https://code.google.com/p/unix4j/).

Comment: What about using CharBuffer that implements CharSequence - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25484164/charbuffer-on-top-of-a-memory-mapped-bytebuffer-without-using-lots-of-heap-space

Comment: @nhahtdh `Pattern.matcher()` doesn't create a new string, but it needs a `CharSequence`. So in most cases I would read the whole file into a `String`/`StringBuilder` (potential OOME), then feed it to `Pattern.matcher()`. *That* was my point.

Comment: Ah, OK. You wanted to perform regex matching and replacement on character stream.

Comment: Maybe this [anwser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22018249/2751621) could help you. And there this [repository](https://github.com/fge/largetext) created by the author of this anwser.

Comment: @emartinelli Thanks, this was exactly what I wanted -- a custom `CharSequence` implementation. Just had little idea of how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Since what you need is actually the `sed` behaviour you can execute it by doing something like this:

```
String[] cmdArray = {"bash", "-c", "sed 's/YourRegex/YourReplaceStr/' inputfile > output"};
Process runCmd = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdArray);
```

I put a bash example but if you want to run it on windows you can install `sed` command through Cygwin and execute the same or just install the sed command for windows which you can download from here:

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm

For windows you could use:

```
String[] cmdArray = {"call", "sed 's/YourRegex/YourReplaceStr/' inputfile > output"};
Process runCmd = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdArray);
```

I don't have windows so cannot test above command, you maybe have to remove `call` or to change the `call` to just `sed`. Another alternative you can try is:

```
String[] cmdArray = {"cmd", "/c", "sed 's/YourRegex/YourReplaceStr/' inputfile > output"};
Process runCmd = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdArray);
```

In this [link](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/42644) you can find an `dir` example executed from java you can adapt it to use sed.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great solution, but I need my code to be able to also run on Windows machines w/o any Cygwin.

Comment: @Bass you can use `sed` in windows too. I've updated the answer with a link to install it